# Unique IDs with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, uniqueidentifier, nosql

If I were building a blog I could use the blog title as the unique identifier and parse it through the URL. However, what if I wanted to use numbers. You know how twitter has www.twitter.com/username/statuses/9834542? Has anyone figured out a nice way of making this work? using "_id" is out of the question since it's way too long.

Comment: You can do a md5(or any) hash of the url and store it in the place of _id.

Answer (score 24):

As long as you can guarantee uniqueness, you're not constrained to using the default "_id" MongoDB supplies.

Therefore, it's down to you how you generate this number.  If you'd like to store this number inside MongoDB, then you could store it in a separate collection and increment it for every new URL required.

Incrementing a field is achieved by using [the `$inc` verb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating), or you may want to take a look at how MongoDB can [atomically update](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations) or increment a value.

Comment: As Alan said, you can provide your own id. So the question is how you can generate it uniquely. Easiest is if you had some sequence server (i.e. something that dishes out a number and then increments, holding a lock so taht it happens atomically. This sequence server could use a single mongo record per sequence

Comment: Could that be Auto-Increment Sequence to create uid?

Answer (score 17):

It can be done by using the [findandmodify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findandmodify+Command) command.

Let's consider we have a special collection named `sequences` and we want to have a sequence for post numbers (named `postid`), you could use code similar to this:

```
> db.runCommand( { "findandmodify" : "sequences",
                   "query" : { "name" : "postid"},
                   "update" : { $inc : { "id" : 1 }},
                   "new" : true } );
```

This command will return atomically the updated (`new`) document together with status. The `value` field contains the returned document if the command completed successfully.

Comment: @BlitzKrieg, as per documentation: "*findandmodify* will behave the same when called through a mongos as long as the collection it is modifying is unsharded. If the collection is sharded, then the query must contain the shard key." So, just don't shard the `sequences` collection?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to add a uniqueness constraint to your own field in MongoDB, use an index.  Then you can use any hashing algorithm you want to generate the number and test it for uniqueness.  The example in the MongoDB documentation is

```
db.things.ensureIndex({firstname: 1, lastname: 1}, {unique: true});
```

which will prevent you from inserting documents with the same firstname AND lastname as another document.

More information is available in the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-UniqueIndexes).

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this problem by creating collection 'sequence' with data:

- name
- currurt value

I'm using [Morhpia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/), so have DAO for it. But you can do it without Morhpia too.
Idea is to use $atomic (probably it can be omitted due updateing 1 instance only) and [$inc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24inc) modifier operator.

Sequence

```
@Entity(value = "sys_sequence", noClassnameStored = true)
public class SequenceM {

    /**
     * Names of entity
     */
    public static enum Entity {
        USER,
        CAPABILITY_HISTORY;

        public String getEntityName() {
            return this.name().toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    @Id
    private ObjectId uid;

    @Property
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Property
    private Long value;

 //..getters/setters/etc
 }
```

Method on SequenceDAO:

```
@NotNull
public Long nextValue(final @NotNull SequenceM.Entity entity) {
    final DB db = this.ds.getDB();
    final WriteConcern writeConcern = getWriteConcern();

    //optimization for JVM instance
    synchronized(entity) {
        do {
            SequenceM sequence = findOne("name", entity.getEntityName());

            final DBObject q = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("name", entity.getEntityName()).add("value", sequence.getValue()).add("$atomic", 1).get();
            final DBObject o = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("$inc", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("value", 1).get()).get();

            WriteResult writeResult = db.getCollection("sys_sequence").update(q, o, false, true, writeConcern);

            if(writeResult.getN() == 1) {
                return sequence.getValue() + 1;
            }
        } while(true);
    }
}

/**
 * Determining writing concern basing on configuration
 */
private WriteConcern getWriteConcern() {
    return isOneNodeOnly ? WriteConcern.SAFE : REPLICATION_SAFE;
}
```

Depending on MongoDB configuration (one node only or master/slave or replica set) you have to use correct WriteConcern. Using REPLICATION_SAFE in one environment with one instance only causes infinite loop.

Comment: What language is this ? :) Hits my eye!

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the ID number is too large to shorten it. However, a tactic can be filled. That is passing from Hex to alphanumeric, thus reducing the number of characters to tulizar and looks more beautiful in the Url. I really served very well ... here is

```
function encode(hex) {
    return new Buffer(hex, 'hex').toString('base64').replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_');
};

function decode(NoHex) {
    return new Buffer( NoHex.replace('-','+').replace('_','/'), 'base64').toString('hex');
};

IdString= MyDoc._id.toString(); 
Idencode = encode( IdString ) // 16 Caracters a-Z and 0-9 
console.log( IdEncode ); //You see That 'aqswedasdfdsadsf'
IdDecode = decode( IdEncode );
IdDecode === IdString // Is true!!!
```

Of course this technique uses the same id, mongo.