# How to create human readable id in MongoDb

Tags: python, mongodb

I need to create human readable id in Mongo like (1,2,3,4,...,n+1) for documents in collection . Is there any way to create they by native mongo tools or I must create they in program's logic.
p.s I use mongoengine as ORM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-SequenceNumbers

> Traditional databases often use increasing sequence numbers for
>   primary keys. In MongoDB, the preferred approach is to use Object IDs
>   instead. The concept is that in a very large cluster of machines, it
>   is easier to create an object ID than have global, uniformly
>   increasing sequence numbers.
>
> However, sometimes you may want a sequence number. You can do this by
>   creating "counter" documents and using the [findAndModify Command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command).

Code sample (from attached link):

```
function counter(name) {
    var ret = db.counters.findAndModify({query:{_id:name}, update:{$inc : {next:1}}, "new":true, upsert:true});
    // ret == { "_id" : "users", "next" : 1 }
    return ret.next;
}

db.users.insert({_id:counter("users"), name:"Sarah C."}) // _id : 1
db.users.insert({_id:counter("users"), name:"Bob D."}) // _id : 2
```

Check also [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352671/unique-ids-with-mongodb)

Comment: Great, I'am lazy log and can't into official documentations ))

Comment: This has an unnecessary read query for each update query. Does not seem scalable.